# Delete a jar locked by server

Tags: java, classloader

I have a web application build using j2ee and java , where user can upload the jar or delete the existing jar and upload a new one. Since server is running and the jars are locked by it, when user choose to delete the jar I am not able to delete it. Is there any way to achieve this ? When I googled I got information about hot deployment or using class loader to unload the jar and then delete it. Whats the good approach to do it ? Any help or suggestion will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If the file is in use by the web server, the file system simply won't let you remove the file as it's locked by the web server.  You have two options.

You could hot deploy a new copy of the jar, for instance if it's a war, say you have (for arguments sake assuming tomcat)...

`ROOT.war`, you can copy into the webapps directory `ROOT#001.war` and all traffic will be moved to this location.  This new war could contain your new jars.

I personally only do this sparingly as I trust the web server to free resources better when it's restarted.  Other than this, your only real option if you want to deploy jars on the fly safely would be to stop the web server, apply the jar, start again.  If you want to have no down time you could look at clustering the environment but it really depends how business critical it is to you.